# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Electron Webview

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on an Electron-Angular application which is using webview to load some other webpage. It ends up with error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" in webView console as shown in snapshot.

This is how, webview loads the url:

```
<webview id="webviewSample" 
    src="{{anotherWebPageUrl}}" nodeintegration style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" #webviewsample></webview>
```

Strangest part is, sometimes it loads webpage successfully and few times it stucks. Any suggestion what is wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a through observation i figured out it was happening due to cache storage. I am yet to check what specific solution i can apply to fix this. Once cache data is deleted it started working again. I will update answer with specific solution applicable soon.

Answer (score -1):

Value interpolation is achieved using two closed curly brackets. Replace `src="{anotherWebPageUrl}"` with `src="{{anotherWebPageUrl}}"`. Try the following

```html
<webview id="webviewSample"  src="{{anotherWebPageUrl}}" nodeintegration style="width:100%;height:100%;" #webviewsample>
</webview>
```

Comment: In that case there might be other errors. Please post the full HTML.

Comment: this is <webview> tag only what i have in my home component routed by app component.